# Dependent controls functionality in Azure AD B2C Signup page

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am using the `AD B2C custom policies` to achieve the `Sign-in` and `Signup`.

In the Signup page, I need to have a dependent controls functionality. Like, once I enter a value in a text box and focus out, a rest API call should be made to pull the information from the Database and need to display that information in the next controls in the read only mode.

For example,

1. If I enter a postal code, It should auto populate the city information
2. If I choose a city, It should auto populate the state and country details.

Please suggest a way to achieve this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript with the custom policies for your requirement.  Once the postal code is entered in the text filed you can call an REST API and generate a dynamic dropdown box with javascript to bind the city details based on the dropdown selection you can bind the required filed.

There is a [sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/selectemail) similar to you requirement. Please refer this it will be helpful